# Why is floating point slicing (slice(0,1,0.1)) allowed in python, but calling the indices method (slice(0,1,0.1).indices) raises TypeError?

Tags: python, slice

Example: `slice(0,1,0.1)` is okay in python 3.7.7, but `slice(0,1,0.1).indices(10)` raises a `Type Error`.

I am wondering what the underlying thought process for this behavior is. Why is it okay to construct float slices, but not okay to call the `indices` method on them? What is a use case for `indices`?

For context: I understand the use case for float slices - I have one myself. I am implementing an object that represents a parameterized, piece wise linear function in arbitrary dimensions defined by a finite set of supporting points.

Comment: Using a float as a step number is a bad idea because of errors in binary representation of floating point numbers unless the float happens to be a power of 2, which 0.1 is not. Best to use integer ranges and steps and then divide them where the calculations are needed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think @ mention only works if that person has already contributed to the question (as far as I am aware)

Comment: They had. They deleted their comment.

Comment: @blhsing yes, that's my assumption, that the developers simply didn't want to take a position on the tricky aspects of float slices. Note, `numpy` does implement this functionality though, so it can be done, of course, there are caveats for the reasons you described

Comment: @blhsing I understand that one is limited by floating point precision in this case; on the other hand slices seem nice to evaluate functions defined on real numbers, e.g. `y = x`. Being able to do `y[0:1:0.1]` to evaluate the function at `0, 0.1, 0.2, ...` seems cleaner than using a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr `slice` objects are generated by the interpreter when we use them in square-bracket notation, and allowing them to be arbitrary allows us to design code that uses them. However, because the built-in list relies on `indices()` to behave properly, that method has to return list-compatible values (i.e. integers), and if it can't, it throws an error.

---

When you do

```
my_obj[1:3:2]
```

the interpreter essentially translates it* as

```
my_obj.__getitem__(slice(1, 3, 2))
```

This is most obvious when using lists, which have special behavior when slices are given, but this behavior is also other datatypes in various popular libraries (e.g. `numpy.array` and `pandas.Dataframe`). These classes implement their own `__getitem__()` methods, that have their own special ways to handle slices.

Now, the built-in list presumably uses `slice.indices()` to decompose the entire slice into a set of individual indices that it can access and then group together and return. List indices can only be integers, and they don't want this functionality to break, so the most consistent way to go about it is to make `slice.indices()` throw an error when it can't produce a list of integers.

They can't restrict `slice` to having only those values, though, because it's an interpreter-generated object that other user-defined classes might want to use. If you design an object like this:

```
class myGenerator:
    def __getitem__(self, s):  # s is a slice
        def gen():
            i = s.start
            while i < s.stop:
                yield i
                i += s.step
        return list(gen())

h = myGenerator()
print(h[1:4:.25])
# [1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75]
print(h[0:1:0.1])
# [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]
```

then it can co-opt slice notation to work however it wants, so we can institute custom behavior for it. But if we were to change `slice.indices()` to use that instead, then it would break the built-in `list` - thus, python doesn't allow us to.

---

*technically, for a lot of built-ins, the python interpreter may take shortcuts and executes hardcoded routines instead of actually translating the notation into function calls and executing them. But for our purposes the analogy works well enough, since it does do that for user-generated objects.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the check if the slice is compatible with `list` is done in `slice.indices` and not in `list.__getitem__` directly?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger I don't know, and I'm not sure there's documentation to be found that details that in particular, but if I had to guess it would be for the sake of people trying to subclass `list`. Whereas `slice` is difficult to subclass effectively because of how the interpreter handles it.